# jQuery: Clean handling for bad status code from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a very simple ajax request:

```
$.get(url, data)
   .done(function () { })
   .fail(function () { })
```

If there is an error at `url`, it will return a status code like "500," for instance.  Apparently, jQuery considers its promise on the `jqxhr` object at this point since it will execute `.done` rather than `.fail`.  My question is twofold:

By default, when is `.fail` triggered with respect to ajax and is there any way to change this default?

Secondly, the only way to have special handling for a bad request seems to be something like:

```
.done(function (msg, tm, jqxhr) {
   if (jqxhr.status < 200 || jqxhr.status >= 300) performFailure();
});
```

Is there a better way to find and handle responses that would be considered "bad?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this further, it seems that jQuery does in fact use `.fail()` correctly.  The problem was that my server was emitting 200 for certain errors.  In other words, this is not a jQuery issue to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) documentation:

> If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, *it will fail
>   silently* unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError()
>   method. Alternatively, as of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the
>   jqXHR object returned by jQuery.get() is also available for error
>   handling.

(emphasis mine)

I haven't done a lot with error handling but it sounds like you might need to call ajaxError to bubble out the error condition.

Comment: `.fail` and `.error` are the same method of the jqxhr object and I am using it.  `.done` executes (same as `.success`) regardless of the status code.  This would appear to be intentional to me.  By the way I'm using jQuery 1.7

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to use .error versus .fail. I was pointing out that error codes fail silently. See the italicized text in my answer. You'll need to have your script call .ajaxError() to land in the error/fail blocks.

Comment: I see what you're saying in your answer; sometimes an error condition is interpreted as 200-OK. Is that what happened in your case? Could you update your answer when you decide how your error handling should work?

Comment: at that point the only way you can handle the error is by inspecting the output

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for the .ajax function, it has a very nice handler for errors: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ You may want to use this function instead of get(). (the two are essentially the same, as you can see from this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/);

an example with your code would be:

```
     $.ajax({
       url: url,
       data: data,
       error: /*error function*/,
       success: /*success function*/,
     });
```

Comment: This does not change the error handling; what happens is the same, actually.

Comment: When the url returns an error code, the error function returned looks like this error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown), it should contain any information you need to handle properly

Comment: the problem was that `error` (or `.fail()`) was not even being called, but it's not a jQuery problem.  Look at my answer.

Comment: I see. Did you not inspect the http request object before you posted?

Comment: no .. it does sound pretty dumb but I was testing this on a production server where I was getting 500s from the ajax requests.  I updated the code on the development server to use `.fail()` and it didn't work; I didn't think the status code sent would be different between the two servers.